# HTML/CSS: Default display value for list element?

Tags: html, css

What is the browser's default display value (like `block` or `inline`) for a list element?

Is there a list where can look up things like that? I tried to look at the HTML5 specs, but as there are so many versions of it I didn't knew which one was binding or if any of them is binding at all as HTML5 is still in development.

Comment: Are you talking about `<li>`? I believe it's `list-item`

Answer (score 8):

Lists (as in the `<ul>` element itself) are displayed as block-level elements. List members display as `list-item`, which is a special case of block-ness.

As for documentation, you can see a full list of block-level elements on the Mozilla Developer Network (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), and likewise inline elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements).

MDN is a great resource, and well worth remembering.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [MDN site for li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li):

- [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/lists.html#h-10.2)
- [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-li-element.html#the-li-element)
- [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)

Comment: Could you please elaborate what that 'living standard' thing is? I also encountered that but I don't understand what this is, I always though the specification is important?

Comment: From the site, "The WHATWG works on a number of technologies that widely get referred to by the buzzword "HTML5". They are organised somewhat arbitrarily based on the preferences of those editing the specifications for those technologies."

Comment: The answer lacks the answer. Mere links are not an adequate answer.

Comment: these are far from mere links my friend; they are the result of 30 seconds of googling. very few heros have dared to venture into these charted waters of "readily available documentation", but those that do will inevitably me critiqued for teaching a man how to fish, rather than just giving the fish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer : "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."  This isn't a place to pretend to be a CS professor and teach programming (or Googling) to people: it's a place to find and provide answers.